# How to store user data as string, and load that string in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, string, userdefaults

I am trying to load a value that has been inputted by the user in the viewDidLoad via a String.  I am using UserDefaults to save the users value that they input into a UITextField (userValue), I then save this to the String 'search'.  I am able to print out the value of search in the GoButton function, and it works fine, but when I load my ViewController as new, the value of 'search' is equal to nil.  The aim here is to have the users previous search saved, and loaded into the UITextField (that is used as a search box) upon loading the ViewController.

Code Below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userValue: UITextField!
    var search: String!
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    if (search != nil)
    {
        userValue.text! = String (search)
    }

}
```

Button Function:

```
@IBAction func GoButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let userSearch: String = userValue.text!

    let perference = UserDefaults.standard
    perference.set(userSearch, forKey: "hello")
    perference.value(forKey: "hello")

    let value = perference.value(forKey: "hello") as! String

    search = value

    print (search) // <<this works, it prints out the users search value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@VishalSharma has the right idea, but the code should probably look more like…

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let search = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "hello") {
       userValue.text = search
   }
}
```

or even more simply…

```
userValue.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "hello")
```

Comment: completely agree with you @Ashley

Comment: *or even more simply* `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "hello")`. Please don't adopt bad code like `value(forKey`. There is no reason at all to use KVC methods with `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Oh crikey, how did I miss that?  Thank you! Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

When you load, search is effectively nil.

So either you read userDefaults in viewDidload or you come through a segue: then you can load search in the prepare.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found it convenient and useful to store all `UserDefault` properties as an extension within the same file along with their getters and setters. It is far easier to maintain, use and read. by using the `#function` keyword for the key you are referencing the variable's name and not a string that can be accidentally changed somewhere else in code.

**UserDefaults.swift**

```
import Foundation
// An Extension to consolidate and manage user defaults. 
extension UserDefaults {
    /// A value Indicating if the user has finished account setup.
    /// - Returns: Bool
    var finishedAcountSetup: Bool {
        get { return bool(forKey: #function) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }

    /// The hello text at the start of the application.
    /// - Returns: String?
    var helloText: String? {
        get { return string(forKey: #function) }
        set {set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }

   //etc...
}
```

When you use these values reference the standard settings:

```
    //Setting
    UserDefaults.standard.helloText = "Updated Hello Text"

    // Getting
    // for non-optional value you can just get:
    let didCompleteSetup = UserDefaults.standard.finishedAcountSetup

    // Otherwise, safely unwrap the value with `if-let-else` so you can set a default value.
    if let text = UserDefaults.standard.helloText {
        // Ensure there is text to set, otherwise use the default
        label.text = text
    } else {
        // helloText is nil, set the default
        label.text = "Some Default Value"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

obviously, it provides nil because when view controller load the search is nil try this.

```
let perference = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (perference.value(forKey: "hello") != nil) {
        search = perference.value(forKey: "hello") as! String
        userValue.text! = String (search)
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift you should be using `if let string = perference.value(forKey: "hello") as? String` rather than fetching it twice

Comment: yes of course, but he has declared the search variable as a string so I just wanted to use that.